# Is there a way to listen to events in Azure AD B2C in real time

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to figure out a way to receive events related to users in Azure B2C. The way I imagined was to subscribe to a particular channel/topic to receive a message when every time a new user registers in B2C. I thought maybe Azure Events Grid be of help but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do it.
any help on the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure AD B2C to return whether the user is new or not in the ID token which you get upon successful authentication. Once you configure it you will receive an attribute named **newUser** in the id_token. You have to enable this by adding it to application claims under authentication flow.

[image: ID Token claim newUser]

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, there's no support for Azure AD B2C as a data source for Event Grid.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-sources

Answer (score 0):

To receive events related to users activities in Azure B2C, you can use `api-connectors`.
There are mainly three events you can hook to, these are:

1. Immediately after federating with an identity provider during
   sign-up
2. Before creating the user account.
3. Before the token is issued.

At these events, Azure B2C will call your API (event handler)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow

[image]